# How to send a message via url with inline buttons

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

I can send message, sample:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/sendMessage?chat_id=@[USERNAME]&text=hello
```

but I want to send message with inline buttons, please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would be the url you are looking for:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/sendMessage?chat_id=[CHAT_ID]&text=[TEXT]&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "hi", "callback_data": "hi"}]]}`

You can pass a JSON to`reply_markup` field. Here this our JSON:

```json
{
  "inline_keyboard": [
    [
      {
        "text": "hi",
        "callback_data": "hi"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I suggest you use an API library to communicate with Telegram. Using bare urls has its own challenges, like sometimes you should url encode your JSON to avoid errors in URL.

For example this is the url-encoded version of above JSON:

```
%7B%22inline_keyboard%22%3A%20%5B%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%20%22hi%22%2C%20%22callback_data%22%3A%20%22hi%22%7D%5D%5D%7D
```

Comment: worked , thanks Ali