# How to send a message with button in shell to Telegram bot?

Tags: bash, shell, telegram-bot

I'm using this and works. But how to put a button blew the message? I tried a lot and still got no idea.

Sorry i forgot to tell it's about Telegram bot api. I want to send a message with button blew.

```sh
function sendadmin(){
    if [ "$admin_id" -ne "$chat_id" ]; then
        curl -s \
        -d parse_mode="MarkdownV2" \
        -d text="$stext" \
        -d chat_id="$admin_id" \
        -d -sendChatAction="videos" \
        -d reply_markup="" \
        https://api.telegram.org/bot$bot_token/sendMessage
    fi
}

stext="||Hello darling||"
sendadmin
```

I tried solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997956/how-to-send-a-message-via-url-with-inline-buttons). And it's return `Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object` error.

Comment: In order to put a button you would need to use a GUI generating library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a GUI message box from a bash script in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/how-to-show-a-gui-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a message via url with inline buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997956/how-to-send-a-message-via-url-with-inline-buttons)

Comment: This would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997956/how-to-send-a-message-via-url-with-inline-buttons/71005858#71005858

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question by editing it in. If your question has been solved by an answer, you can accept it, if you solved the problem yourself you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reply=$(cat <<-EOF
{
    "inline_keyboard": [
        [
            {
                "text": "Button1",
                "callback_data": "lt"
            },
            {
                "text": "Button1",
                "callback_data": "rt"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "Button3",
                "callback_data": "ls"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
EOF
)
```

Using `car <<EOF EOF` to give that json format to a variable and then use it like `reply_markup="$reply"` . I just found out this way.